# sorting a string array and an int array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am working on making a dating website on java. I want to find the three most compatible matches for a user. So i have an array of three ints and if a user is more compatible the least compatible score will be replaced. I do this using selection sort. I also need the references to be correct so i Can return the proper names. I can't figure our how to sort the string array. Thanks for the help and heres the code:

```
  public void findMatches(String matchName)
  {
  String nameA = null;
  String nameB = null;
  String nameC = null;
  int matchA = -1;
  int matchB = -2;
  int matchC = -3; 
  Member ref = userList.get(matchName);
  if(ref.getDesiredAge()>=45 && ref.getDesiredSex().equalsIgnoreCase("Male"))
  {
     for(String na : userListMaleOld.keySet())
     {
        Member refA = userListMaleOld.get(na);
        int numberOfMatches=findQuestionMatches(ref, refA);
        int [] counts = {matchA, matchB, matchC};
        String [] names = {nameA, nameB, nameC};
        counts = doSelectionSort(counts);
        if(numberOfMatches>counts[0]);
        {
           counts[0] = numberOfMatches;
           ?!?!?!?!?!??!??!??!WHAT HERE?!?!
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you make a class?

Comment: To hold a pair of `String` and `int`?  So you can just sort objects of the class, and the `String` and `int` stay paired no matter what because they're just properties of the objects which are being sorted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Map` instead.

Concrete this means that you can do something like this:

```
Map<User, Integer> bestMatches = new HashMap<>();

void validateUser(User user, int value) {
  if(bestMatches.size() < 3) {
     bestMatches.put(User, 3);
     return;
  }

  Map<User, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<User, Integer>();
  User minValue = Collections.min(bestMatches.values());
  if(value > minValue) {
     for(Map.Entry<User, Integer> entry: bestMatches.entrySet()) {
           if(entry.getValue() != minValue) {
              newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
           }
     }
     newMap.put(user, value);
  }

  bestMatches = newMap;
}
```

It's probably not very optimized, but you can fix that as you wish. Basically just check if the value of the current user is higher than the lowest value among the existing users in the collection. If it is, create a new collection with the 2 other users and assign that to your first collection.

For large datasets this would be impractical, but we're talking about 3 users here so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If these are actually supposed to be name / score pairs (i.e. scoreA is the score for nameA, scoreB is the score for nameB and so on), then the *simple* solution is something like this:

```
  public class Score {
     private String name;
     private int score;
     // Declare a constructor and getters
  }
```

... and to use this appropriately.  For instance, you could now sort a list or array of these `Score` objects, by name or by score.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to figure out what the code you've shown us is supposed to do, and how it is supposed interact with the rest of your code.  Therefore, it is not entirely clear how you should modify your code to use this.  And it maybe that you are best of *starting over* following Jeroen's advice and completely redesigning your data structures.